# PHP: Fusion chart tutorial

Tags: php, interactive, data-visualization, fusioncharts

After researching into various charting solutions fusion charts looks like it will be most suited to my needs.

I'm finding it difficult to get a good detailed tutorial on how to create a chart that lets the user can click on different data to open a new window.

For example a pie chart of backup statistics (successful, failed, missing). I'd like to be able to click on the successful slice which directs to a new page showing all the backups with status success.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Jonesy

Answer (score 1):

I use FusionCharts a lot and it is called Drill-Down charts. This is the tutorial:

- [Creating Drill-Down Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/Docs/Contents/DrillDown/Simple.html)

All you need to do is put an attribute like this: `link='DemoLinkPages/DemoLink1.html'` and remember to URLEncode this link.

Comment: thanks for this, sorry I took so long getting back to you. I need to learn fusion charts before I'll tackle this though. Will be getting back to you. Which language are you using for fusioncharts?